# Most efficient solution for reading CLOB to String, and String to CLOB in Java?

Tags: java, stringbuilder, clob

I have a big CLOB (more than 32kB) that I want to read to a String, using StringBuilder. How do I do this in the most efficient way? I can not use the "int length" constructor for StringBuilder since the lenght of my CLOB is longer than a "int" and needs a "long" value.

I am not that confortable with the Java I/O classes, and would like to get some guidance.

**Edit** - *I have tried with this code for clobToString():*

```
private String clobToString(Clob data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Reader reader = data.getCharacterStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String line;
        while(null != (line = br.readLine())) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // handle this exception
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle this exception
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do once you read the CLOB into a String?

Comment: Do you mean CLOB in the database sense, or just "large string"?

Comment: Yes, it is a CLOB from an DB2 data base.

Comment: The CLOB contains a large XML-string that will be passed to JAXB.

Comment: I am wondering if there is any helpful classes in Java NIO for this.

Comment: I found some helpful info about CLOB in this document: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/clob.html

But I don't understand the use of .getSubString(1,len), since len is a long and not an int.

Comment: @Sanoj: You say that the size of your CLOB is larger than an `int` can store - that's 4GB of string data. Are you sure about this?

Comment: No, not yet, but I have a feeling what kind of problems I can get of this, so I will do some more testing. I got good advice here, thanks.

Comment: "more than 32kB" - You mean 32 bit?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I can not use the "int length" constructor for `StringBuilder` since the length of my CLOB is longer than a `int` and needs a `long` value.

If the CLOB length is greater than fits in an int, the CLOB data won't fit in a String either. You'll have to use a streaming approach to deal with this much XML data.

If the actual length of the CLOB is smaller than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, just force the `long` to `int` by putting `(int)` in front of it.

Comment: Indeed, if the CLOB size is bigger than 2^32 bytes, you've got big problems

Comment: I would suggest writing it to a file, if he need the whole CLOB to process

Answer (score 54):

Ok I will suppose a general use, first you have to download [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/), there you will find an utility class named IOUtils which has a method named copy();

Now the solution is: get the input stream of your CLOB object using getAsciiStream() and pass it to the copy() method.

```
InputStream in = clobObject.getAsciiStream();
StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(in, w);
String clobAsString = w.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice. But I leavy the question open little bit more, because I would prefer a solution that only uses the standard library.

Comment: I already have the Apache Commons library loaded so this is the perfect solution.  Thanks!

Comment: getAsciiStream will give you headaches if you use unicode. (or any characters falling outside of ascii)

Comment: I changed `InputStream` to `Reader` and `clobObject.getAsciiStream()` to `clobObject.getCharacterStream()` to prevent encoding issues.

Comment: `IOUtils.copy(in, w)` is deprecated, use `IOUtils.copy(in, w, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead

Answer (score 37):

What's wrong with:

```
clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length());
```

?

For example Oracle `oracle.sql.CLOB` performs `getSubString()` on internal `char[]` which defined in `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection` and just `System.arraycopy()` and next wrap to `String`... You never get faster reading than `System.arraycopy()`.

**UPDATE** Get driver [ojdbc6.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html), decompile `CLOB` implementation, and study which case could be faster based on the internals knowledge.

Comment: Leaves a lot of newlines characters in the string.

Comment: @Gervase Newlines can be significant in XML.  Anyway, you shoud trim useless spaces and newlines before storing it to the DB.

Comment: Some points to clear: What happen if clob.length() is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE? What's jar contains oracle.sql.CLOB?

Comment: @Stephan I studied `ojdbc6.jar`. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is a limit for array length for **JDK Platform 2** and String hold chars in array. So you out of luck for > 2 GiB CLOBs... Try streaming approach because you can't hold that data with pure Java memory model (unless you use some native extension and 64-bit platform with enough system memory).

Comment: what's wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249238/java-sql-sqlrecoverableexception-while-fetching-clob-data-using-hibernate-orac  ... I face the same problem when SQL close connection to CLOB data on production

Comment: @MarekBernád OK. I believe that you have problem because you cross transaction / connection boundaries. It is the problem with cumbersome frameworks that hides resource management. If you in managed EE environment access getter inside `@Transactional` )) *If you bother with efficiency Hibernate is not a good framework*.

Answer (score 23):

My answer is just a flavor of the same. But I tested it with serializing a zipped content and it worked. So I can trust this solution unlike the one offered first (that use readLine) because it will ignore line breaks and corrupt the input.

```
/*********************************************************************************************
 * From CLOB to String
 * @return string representation of clob
 *********************************************************************************************/
private String clobToString(java.sql.Clob data)
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        final Reader         reader = data.getCharacterStream();
        final BufferedReader br     = new BufferedReader(reader);

        int b;
        while(-1 != (b = br.read()))
        {
            sb.append((char)b);
        }

        br.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        log.error("SQL. Could not convert CLOB to string",e);
        return e.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        log.error("IO. Could not convert CLOB to string",e);
        return e.toString();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Good job, thank you

Answer (score 5):

If you really must use only standard libraries, then you just have to expand on Omar's solution a bit. (Apache's IOUtils is basically just a set of convenience methods which saves on a lot of coding)

You are already able to get the input stream through `clobObject.getAsciiStream()`

You just have to "manually transfer" the characters to the StringWriter:

```
InputStream in = clobObject.getAsciiStream();
Reader read = new InputStreamReader(in);
StringWriter write = new StringWriter();

int c = -1;
while ((c = read.read()) != -1)
{
    write.write(c);
}
write.flush();
String s = write.toString();
```

Bear in mind that

1. If your clob contains more character than would fit a string, this won't work.
2. Wrap the InputStreamReader and StringWriter with BufferedReader and BufferedWriter respectively for better performance.

Comment: That looks similar to the code i provided in my question, are there any key differences between them that I don't see? In example in a performance point of view?

Comment: Oops, i missed out on your code fragment! It's somewhat similar, but bear in mind that by just grabbing the BufferedReader.readLine(), you'll miss out on the linebreaks.

Comment: Small Correction Line 2 should be Reader read = new InputStreamReader(in);

Comment: No, no, no. `getAsciiStream()` forces ASCII encoding and corrupts all non-ASCII-characters. What you're doing is getting an `InputStream` (bytes) from a character source, and then immediately turning them back into characters using a random (platform default) encoding on `InputStreamReader`. It's a redundant operation except for the fact that it corrupts non-ASCII data. Just read from the `getCharacterStream()` `Reader` directly and write to the `StringWriter`.

Answer (score 4):

If using Mule, below are the steps.

Follow below steps.

Enable streaming in the connector i.e. progressiveStreaming=2

Typecast DB2 returned CLOB to java.sql.Clob (IBM Supports this type cast)

Convert that to character stream (ASCII stream sometimes may not support some special characters). So you may to use getCharacterStream()

That will return a "reader" object which can be converted to "String" using common-io (IOUtils).

So in short, use groovy component and add below code.

```
clobTest = (java.sql.Clob)payload.field1 
bodyText = clobTest.getCharacterStream() 
targetString = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(bodyText)
payload.PAYLOADHEADERS=targetString return payload
```

**Note:** Here I'm assuming "payload.field1" is holding clob data.

That's it!

Regards Naveen

Answer (score 2):

A friendly helper method using apache commons.io

```
Reader reader = clob.getCharacterStream();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(reader, writer);
String clobContent = writer.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String tryClob2String(final Object value)
{
    final Clob clobValue = (Clob) value;
    String result = null;

    try
    {
        final long clobLength = clobValue.length();

        if (clobLength < Integer.MIN_VALUE || clobLength > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        {
            log.debug("CLOB size too big for String!");
        }
        else
        {
            result = clobValue.getSubString(1, (int) clobValue.length());
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        log.error("tryClob2String ERROR: {}", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (clobValue != null)
        {
            try
            {
                clobValue.free();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                log.error("CLOB FREE ERROR: {}", e);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String readClob(Clob clob) throws SQLException, IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((int) clob.length());
    Reader r = clob.getCharacterStream();
    char[] cbuf = new char[2048];
    int n;
    while ((n = r.read(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length)) != -1) {
        sb.append(cbuf, 0, n);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The above approach is also very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String convertToString(java.sql.Clob data)
{
    final StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        final Reader         reader = data.getCharacterStream();
        final BufferedReader br     = new BufferedReader(reader);

        int b;
        while(-1 != (b = br.read()))
        {
            builder.append((char)b);
        }

        br.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        log.error("Within SQLException, Could not convert CLOB to string",e);
        return e.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        log.error("Within IOException, Could not convert CLOB to string",e);
        return e.toString();
    }
    //enter code here
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String clobToString(final Clob clob) throws SQLException, IOException {
        try (final Reader reader = clob.getCharacterStream()) {
            try (final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()) {
                IOUtils.copy(reader, stringWriter);
                return stringWriter.toString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

CLOB are like Files, you can read parts of it easily like this

```
// read the first 1024 characters
String str = myClob.getSubString(0, 1024);
```

and you can overwrite to it like this

```
// overwrite first 1024 chars with first 1024 chars in str
myClob.setString(0, str,0,1024);
```

I don't suggest using StringBuilder and fill it until you get an Exception, almost like adding numbers blindly until you get an overflow. Clob is like a text file and the best way to read it is using a buffer, in case you need to process it, otherwise you can stream it into a local file like this

```
int s = 0;
File f = new File("out.txt");
FileWriter fw new FileWriter(f);

while (s < myClob.length())
{
    fw.write(myClob.getSubString(0, 1024));
    s += 1024;
}

fw.flush();
fw.close();
```