# Converting nvarchar(max) data type to string in Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008

I am executing following sql query on SQL Server 2008 using jTDS API:

```
SELECT  a , b , c FROM [db].[dbo].[table] where d = 1;
```

And data type for these three fields are as follows:

```
a  -- nvarchar(255)
b  -- nvarchar(255)
c  -- nvarchar(max)
```

When I execute query using Java, the string values for a and b are plain text, but for c I am getting following value:

```
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ClobImpl@2b34fb
```

It seems it is stored as object, how can I convert it to normal string ?

Comment: What is the type in Java? DBVT_STRING? DBVT_ASTRING? Something else?

Comment: When you are getting the values off the `ResultSet`, I take you've already tried `getString(column)` and `getCharacterStream(column)`?

Comment: DBVT_STRING ? , even i tried , toString on it, it's still same

Comment: Might want to have a look at this link:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/forums/forum/104389/topic/4623409

Comment: Found this, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169732/most-efficient-solution-for-reading-clob-to-string-and-string-to-clob-in-java

Comment: Nice and thanks for the answer post; hopefully it helps someone else

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tried the Link Sent by @Roberto Navaron , It worked, just passed object to this method,   type cast it to clob and it returns string

```
private String clobToString(Clob data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Reader reader = data.getCharacterStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String line;
        while(null != (line = br.readLine())) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // handle this exception
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle this exception
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or we can use this -

- String   getNString(int columnIndex)
- String   getNString(String columnLabel)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html