# convert String to Clob and vice versa in Hibernate

Tags: string, hibernate, clob

Suppose that I have a Class:

```
class EventTransaction {
    .....
    private Clob dataXML;

    public Clob getDataXML() {
       return dataXML;
    }

    public void setDataXML(Clob dataXML) {
       this.dataXML = dataXML;
    }
}
```

And Hibernate mapping xml:

```
 <property name="dataXML" type="java.sql.Clob">
        <column name="XML" sql-type="CLOB"/>
 </property>
```

In java code, how to I convert a String to Clob and vice versa to save into to the database:

```
Ex: EventTransaction et = new EventTransaction();
    String xml = "fdfsafafafa";
    et.setDataXML(convertStringToClob(xml));
    HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(et);
```

Could you please help how to implement function **convertStringToClob**(String data);

Thanks,

Comment: I'm waiting for your acceptance!

Answer (score 18):

Do this

```
@Column(name="XML")
@Lob
private String dataXML;

public String getDataXML() {
   return dataXML;
}

public void setDataXML(String dataXML) {
   this.dataXML = dataXML;
}
```

So there is no need to convert, and everything is done by Hibernate.

I showed it using annotations, the same thing can be done using `.hbm.xml` files.

Comment: If we do that we will get problem with 64k limitation. I want to save a larger xml file like string

Comment: And who limits you to 64k?

Comment: Wow uhm... you just saved me about 20 lines of code, a cache for "de-clob-ed Strings" and a workaround for serialisation... Just goes to show you that you should know your tools (Hibernate) before using them. Thanks!

Comment: That 64k is limitation of the database, just select proper type in DB and there will be no limitation!

Comment: The most clean and simplest I've seen. Thanks dude!

Comment: @hoangnguyen If you are using MySQL there are at least 2 types of LOBs one is a small LOB with 64k limit, and one a big LOB without that limitation (I cannot recall the names now as I am not working with MySQL for a long time).... it is up to you to use proper one according to your needs,

Answer (score 5):

Here is code I made a long time ago to convert a Clob to a String. It's meant to be used in a utility class.

```
    public static String convertClobToString(Clob clob) throws IOException, SQLException {
            Reader reader = clob.getCharacterStream();
            int c = -1;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                 sb.append(((char)c));
            }

            return sb.toString();
     }
```

And if I am not mistaken, to create a Clob you would do something like this

```
     Clob myClobFile = new SerialClob("my string".toCharArray());
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB

Comment: I get this exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB

Comment: Import Clob interface from java.sql.Clob and the other should be javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob. Personally I never had to use this with hibernate, I used the @Lob annotation and on my Table declared the column as CLOB.

Comment: If I do that I cannot save a large XML String, we cannot save a string with length > 64000 characters

Comment: @hoangnguyen What is your database? I have experience with Oracle, and I know there is no such limitation when you declare the column type as CLOB in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation of 64000 characters is on the database side when you declare the XML column as VARCHAR (and not on Java String), so as long as your column XML is a CLOB, it should work.

Excerpt from working code:

Entity:

```
private String xml;
```

SQL (ORACLE):

```
XML       CLOB,
```

Hibernate mapping:

```
<property name="xml" type="java.lang.String">
    <column name="XML" length="999999" />
</property>
```

If you want to store the XML as a file, then you should rather use BLOBs as shown below :

Entity:

```
private byte[] xmlFile;
```

SQL (ORACLE):

```
XML       BLOB,
```

Hibernate mapping:

```
<property name="xmlFile" type="java.io.File">
    <column name="XML" />
</property>
```

Comment: I declared XML column is CLOB. The problem is still happen.

Comment: try declaring the dataXML field in your class as String (instead of Clob); change the XML mapping accordingly. In the code snippet above (extracted from working code) String is used instead of Clob on the Java side