# Select from H2 adds "clob:" to texts in clojure

Tags: select, text, clojure, h2

I am using a h2 database with clojure. I made a table and put some data in like this

```
(j/create-table :locations
    [:id "bigint primary key auto_increment"]
    [:title "varchar (255)"]
    [:part "clob"])

  (j/insert-records :locations
    {:title "Steven Gerrard: I'm not the new Beckham" :part "He might not have the Becks appeal -- but Steven Gerrard says he's ready to light up Hollywood in his own way..."}))
    )
   )
```

And then I selected the data

```
(defn newest []
 (database/mysql-db)
 (let [results (j/with-connection db-spec
                  (j/with-query-results res
                    ["select id, title, part from locations"]
                    (doall res)))]
    results))
```

And I used the data on a clostache page

```
<div class="container">
    <sections>
         {{#newest}}
           <p style="padding-bottom: 15px;">{{title}}<p>
           <p style="padding-bottom: 15px;">{{part}}<p>
         {{/newest}}
     </sections>
  </div>
```

On the page i get

```
Steven Gerrard: I'm not the new Beckham

clob0: 'He might not have the Becks appeal -- but Steven Gerrard says he''s ready to light up Hollywood in his own way...'
```

How can I remove the `clob0:` string that is attached to the text I have in the database? This happens even if I use `text` instead of `clob` for the part column in my database.

Answer (score 3):

The 'clob0:' prefix is not actually attached to your data in database.

The reason you get this is because ResultSet returns instances of class `java.sql.Clob` for column "part" (for both CLOB and TEXT data types, they are actually [synonyms](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#clob_type)).

It's not proper way to convert Clob to String by using `toString()` method, implementation is free to return any human-readable form. Correct way may be found in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169732/most-efficient-solution-for-reading-clob-to-string-and-string-to-clob-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

You might have noticed that new lines get lost by the above... something like this adds them back in...

```
(defn clob-to-string [clob]
        "Turn an Clob into a String, with new new lines"
    (with-open [rdr (java.io.BufferedReader. (.getCharacterStream clob))]
      (let [lseq (line-seq rdr)
            butlast-line (butlast lseq)
            butlast-line-mapped (map (fn [l] (str l "\n")) butlast-line)
            last-line (last lseq)
            all-lines-with-newline (concat butlast-line-mapped last-line)
            ]
        (apply str all-lines-with-newline)
        )))
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `clob:` with:

```
(defn clob-to-string [row]
  (assoc row :text (with-open [rdr (java.io.BufferedReader. (.getCharacterStream (:text row)))]
    (apply str (line-seq rdr)))))

(defn newest []
 (database/mysql-db)
 (j/query db-spec
          ["select id, title, text from news"]
          :row-fn clob-to-string
    ))
```