# Convert Clob to String

Tags: java, string, clob

How can I get String out of Clob. I did google it, but

```
myClob.getSubString(0, (int) info.length()));
```

is the only thing I get. Console says:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call    at
>   oracle.sql.CLOB.getSubString(CLOB.java:278)   at
>   ru.tenet.es09.dao.CompanyDAOImpl.get(CompanyDAOImpl.java:72)  at
>   ru.tenet.es09.dao.CompanyDAOImpl.getList(CompanyDAOImpl.java:132)     at
>   ru.tenet.es09.dao.AddressDAOImpl.getList(AddressDAOImpl.java:59)  at
>   ru.tenet.es09.Test.main(Test.java:11)

It points on `getSubString()` method. What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient solution for reading CLOB to String, and String to CLOB in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169732/most-efficient-solution-for-reading-clob-to-string-and-string-to-clob-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using standard JDBC, once you have a `ResultSet` object you should be able to call `ResultSet#getString("clob_field_name")` to retrieve your CLOB data.

Comment: It will be a cast exception

Comment: If you cast it to oracle.sql.CLOB then yes, if you do String clobData = resultSet.getString("clob_field") you'll be fine.

Comment: This worked for me:
`if (obj!=null && obj instanceof oracle.sql.CLOB) {obj = rs.getString(i);}`.
`

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late to this party!.  Here is the one liner i used from hibernate library.  If hibernate is already integrated to project then we can use annotations to convert clob to java String.  In my case i had custom result transformer which read data from multiple tables after costly join.  In the resultSetTransformer the below line does the job.

```
ClobType.INSTANCE.toString((Clob) tuple[2])
// org.hibernate.type.ClobType
```

Comment: god bless u my friend

Answer (score 0):

this my way (sorry my english)

```
        res = ps.executeQuery();
        try {
            while (res.next()) {
                System.out.println(res.getClob(1));//confirm data
                sRet = res.getString(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            ps.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting String to CLOB

```
SOobject.setLongStringField( new SerialClob(entityString.toCharArray()));//Converting String to CLOB
```

Convert Clob to String

```
public String getLongStringField() {
         Reader reader = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                reader = longStringField.getCharacterStream();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                return IOUtils.toString(bufferedReader);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                throw new RuntimeException("Error while reading String from CLOB", e);
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedReader);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a java method which can create string from a CLOB object:

```
 public String clobToString(Clob data) {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Reader reader = data.getCharacterStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

            String line;
            while(null != (line = br.readLine())) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // handle this exception
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle this exception
        }
        return sb.toString();
```

}