# Conversion of Clob to String slow

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbctemplate

I have an Oracle table that contains a number of clob fields. The clob fields themselves are plain text CSV files that are about 4kb-8kb in size. There are about 200 records in my table. I have a Sql query written that I run in JdbcTemplate that runs pretty quickly in JdbcTemplate (about 2 seconds).

Unfortunately, when I try to extract the clob field into a string for all 200 records, the execution time goes from 2 seconds to over 20 seconds, which is far too slow.

I am using the following line to convert the clob to a string.

```
String clobValue = clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length());
```

It seems to be this conversion that is killing performance for me. Are there any alternatives open to me on the Oracle or Java side to speed this up?

I have tried some other suggestions from here, but performance doesn't improve - [Most efficient solution for reading CLOB to String, and String to CLOB in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169732/most-efficient-solution-for-reading-clob-to-string-and-string-to-clob-in-java)

Surely there is a different, or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: That's pretty fishy, 1 second per record is too much in any case. Did you try to profile both the java side and the db queries issued to see where the time is lost?

Comment: The query to get the records takes 2 seconds. Each conversion of a clob to a string takes .1 seconds. That gets us to 20 seconds in total. I suppose I could multi-thread it...

Comment: I have one query that gets all 200 records at once. The issue I have isn't the query or getting the results in time, it's extracting the clob's on Java once I have them.

Comment: I assume you have to loop over the result, some `while (rs.next())`, that could cause further fetches under the hood that evade observation as of now. `executeQuery` only fetches the first bunch of records, depending on fetch size. Seems, default oracle/jdbc fetch size is [10 rows](https://medium.com/@FranckPachot/oracle-postgres-jdbc-fetch-size-3012d494712), you have 200 rows, so there will be another 19 fetches. Just trying to take the problem apart and find the actual cause. Converting the internal byte[] of clob to a String won't be the culprit, I'd assume.

Comment: Also seems, you arrived at your number by averaging the run time after executeQuery per record, did you? Hm, and did you use the [native `oracle.sql.*` classes](https://web.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10gR2/java.102/b14355/oralob.htm#i1058044) for access or did you go the generic way?