# Alternatives for Ingesting Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY Data into GeoMesa

Tags: oracle, spatial, wkt, geomesa

I am currently working on a project that involves ingesting spatial data from an Oracle database into GeoMesa using the JDBC converter. My source data is in the Oracle-specific SDO_GEOMETRY format.

My initial approach was to convert the SDO_GEOMETRY data to the Well-Known Text (WKT) representation using the SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY function. Afterwards, I planned to convert this WKT into a string format using the TO_CHAR function so I can ingest it into GeoMesa. However, I encountered a challenge with this approach. Oracle's TO_CHAR function can handle only up to 4000 characters, but some of my converted WKT data exceeds this limit. As a result, I am unable to convert and ingest my data.

I am looking for alternative solutions to this problem. Is there a more efficient way to convert the SDO_GEOMETRY data into a format that can be ingested by GeoMesa, without hitting the character limit? Is there a direct method to convert the Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY into a format (like Well-Known Binary or others) which can be handled directly by GeoMesa without the 4000 character limit issue?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-2AF592C1-7FAB-452F-A276-1F1C09013B97), which returns a `CLOB` instead of a `VARCHAR`. GeoMesa doesn't have any `CLOB` handling though, unless `.toString` returns something useful. You'd probably need to implement a [custom transformer function](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/convert/extending.html#adding-new-transformation-functions) to [turn the `CLOB` into a `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169732/most-efficient-solution-for-reading-clob-to-string-and-string-to-clob-in-java).

A function like that would be generally useful, so please [contribute it back](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md) to the GeoMesa project if you implement it!

Comment: Hello, I have created a custom transformer function in a form of .jar to turn the CLOB into a String. Is there anyway I can contribute it back to GeoMesa project?

Comment: @auliama yes! You would fork https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa, create a branch with your changes, then open a PR. See https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md for full details. Don't worry about creating a JIRA ticket, I can do that for you once you make the PR. thanks!